# Smoother way to check attribute for several states

Tags: java, if-statement

I recently tumbled about something from which I think there should be a smoother way, but I couldn't find one.

In one of my methods I have to check where exactly the `ActionEvent e` comes from. Since I have multiple buttons which should call the same method upon clicking, I checked for them like this:

```
if (e.getSource() == btn1 || e.getSource() == btn2 || e.getSource() == btn3)
```

for me this does not look that nice, because I have to call `e.getSource()`for every button. I thought there should be something like:

```
if(e.getSource() == btn1 || btn2 || btn3)
```

I know this does not work, but I hope you get the concept of what I want to achieve. If its a duplicate, I am sorry, but I couldn't find it. If its not possible at all, then I'll have to live with it.

Comment: At the very least you could store the result of `getSource()` in a local variable so that you're not repeatedly calling it

Comment: *"Since I have multiple buttons which should call the same method upon clicking"* - Doesn't make much sense when you need `if/else` blocks to split the behaviour. So your smoother way is: write better methods.

Comment: What about `Object source = e.getSource()` and just use that? Also you could extract the check into a method and use that in your `if` condition.

Comment: @JonK then i would still have the same as before only with substituting the call with a variable. what i want is to only have to call it once

Comment: how about this -> `if(Arrays.asList(btn1, btn2, btn3).contains(e.getSource()))`

Comment: @Tom its a bit more complex gui with several `cancel` buttons which should all call `dispose()`

Comment: They still can call `dispose()` but that doesn't mean that their action listeners only have one method to call. You could also have something like "cancel button 1 - 3 -> method 1 (which calls a Method X which then contains `dispose()`) and cancel button 4 - 6 -> method 2 which also calls Method X). Try to avoid that `if` in the first place instead of making that look nicer.

Comment: @Tom its just one `ActionListener` for all the buttons. the reason for that is irrelevant. all that matters for me is whether there is a smoother way or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hide away your lengthy code in a function with **variable arguments**.

```
public boolean checkSource( Object source, Object... buttons){
   for( Object btn: buttons)
       if( source == btn )
           return true;
}
```

Then you'd have to list the buttons:

```
checkSource( e.getSource(), btn1, btn2, btn3, ... );
```

Or, with **lambdas** and the **Predicate** interface:

```
Predicate<Object> p1 = ( btn  -> btn == e.getSource() );
...
if( p1.test( btn1 ) || p1.test( btn2 ) || p1.test( btn3 ) || ...)
```

Comment: that would be a good approach, but is there a way like the one i gave an example for?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Maybe a lambda way, that I still couldn't wrap my head arnd.

Comment: @dev8080 don't you think it is a bit of an overkill? What advantage it would have over a Set or different data structure and for instance contains operation like in my solution?

Comment: @MateuszChrzaszcz True, your (or Ömer Erden's) solution is better than all, I just gave my two cents. I wouldn't call it overkill though. The OP just wants to see it in his way.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to address this issue.
If states `btn1`, `btn2` and `btn3` represent some concept that could be logically represented together, you could create a `Set` of these statuses.
Then in your if condition you would simply have:

```
//somewhere in your code
private final Set<YourType> buttons = new HashSet<>(btn1,btn2,btn3);


//and here is how you would use it
if(buttons.contains(e.getSource())) {
  //do something here 
}
```

Naming this set in a proper way would be important too in order to show what concept they represent that they are grouped together.

Comment: It makes even more sense if you follow clean code rules and extract condition to separate method with a proper name ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement.

```
switch (e.getSource()) {
    case btn1:
        // Do stuff for button 1 here
        break;
    case btn2:
        // Do stuff for button 2 here
        break;
    case btn3:
        // Do stuff for button 3 here
        break;
    default:
        // Do stuff for all other buttons here
}
```

If you want to do the same thing for all 3 buttons:

```
switch (e.getSource()) {
        case btn1:
            // Don't break
        case btn2:
            // Don't break
        case btn3:
            // Do stuff for buttons 1 2 and 3
            break;
        default:
            // Do stuff for all other buttons here
    }
```

Comment: same as the if, only acceptable thing would be something like `case btn1, btn2, btn3:`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I misunderstood the question. I updated my answer to reflect what you've said.

Comment: still i would have to write `case xyz` for every condition